Is it possible to run a Solana node with 128gb of ram?
I am curious if it is possible to configure a node so that it only requires 128gb of ram? Obviously I would have to cut a lot of things out in terms of what's in memory

Official Solana Validator Requirements doc suggests a minimum of 256GB
https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-reqs.
Running below these specs can lead to instability and issues.
